# Best way to count parent items in GTK# TreeStore

Tags: c#, gtk#

I am new to GTK and I am learning to use a TreeStore.  I am using C#.

I would like to count the parent items in a TreeStore so that when I append an item I can concatenate the title with an appropriate number. (e.g. "Product 0", "Product 1" etc.

I have found a way to do what I want by iterating through the entire tree and counting the items.  Like this:

```
trs_inspectionStore.GetIterFirst (out iter);    // Go to first item in store.
    int n = 0;
    while (trs_inspectionStore.IterIsValid (iter))  // Loop while the iter is valid
    {
        n++;
        trs_inspectionStore.IterNext (ref iter);    // Next item!
    }
    Console.WriteLine (n);
```

I am wondering if there is a better way.  I was hoping to find some Count property or something along those lines.  Any ideas? Or am I already using the best method?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this problem myself:

To count the number of top-level rows in a TreeStore, use the NChildren() method of a model.  This method is generally used to count the number of children of a row, and you pass it an 'Iter' object as a parameter.  But if, instead, you call it with no Iter (zero parameters) it returns a count of the number of top level rows:

```
int count = Model.IterNChildren();
```

Comment: Took a surprisingly high amount of time to find this.